# Poisson and Negative Binomial

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

I know that there is a relationship between Poisson and the Negative Binomial but is there any good sources where they rigorously treat this comparison mathematically?

Comment: What is this relationship exactly?

Comment: I actually read this pdf https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.casact.org/pubs/proceed/proceed60/60020.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwir85vN-8TdAhWLMN4KHaoODDEQFjARegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2SnDaMFlwzPEOwhvLIbE7x&cshid=1537287941708 comparing the two distributions for the given experiment. But I do not fully understand so I was wondering if there are some texts which clarify the relationship between the two distributions in detail.

Comment: Please add this info in your original post.